# Yet another jquery ajax file upload issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload

This is probably repost as I might not searched deep enough in stackoverflow, though a few posts that I found haven't helped me enough. So I'm trying to do a simple thing - upload an image using ajax. I've got this HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline" id="navigationLinkCreationForm" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nuorodos pavadinimas" id="linkName" />
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
        Įkelti ikoną(1:1)<input id="selectNavigationIcon" name="navigationIcon" type="file" style="display: none;">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="createLinkButton" value="Sukurti nuorodą" />
</form>
```

Then I've got this ajax:

```
$('#createLinkButton').on('click', uploadFiles);

function uploadFiles(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($('#navigationLinkCreationForm'));

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../php_includes/uploadNavigationIcon.php',
        data:formData,
        success: function (data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false
    });
}
```

And finally I've got a simple uploadNavigationIcon.php file which just outputs "S" if files have been submitted

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['files']))
    {
        echo "S";
    }
```

After running this I'm just getting empty output, which just means that files weren't submitted.

Comment: You will never get a file with $_GET variable. file upload has its own way. Print $_FILES. and read file upload documentation here
 http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, its a tested and working code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#upload').on('click', function() {
        var file_data = $('#pic').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);

        $.ajax({
                url         : 'upload.php',     // point to server-side PHP script 
                dataType    : 'text',           // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                cache       : false,
                contentType : false,
                processData : false,
                data        : form_data,                         
                type        : 'post',
                success     : function(output){
                    alert(output);              // display response from the PHP script, if any
                }
         });
         $('#pic').val('');                     /* Clear the file container */
    });
});
```

upload.php

```
<?php
    if ( $_FILES['file']['error'] > 0 ){    // file data can't be fetched by using $_GET
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']))
        {
            echo "File Uploaded Successfully";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Yep, I'm so stupid trying to get stuff from $_GET... That was the problem, thanks bud! Got it working now :) Accepting your answer is 3mins..

Comment: It is just a mind slip and happens with every one. Sounds good that your problem is solved :)
Enjoy the coding